# putty is showing garbeled text in ubuntu but works correctly in windows for same data

Tags: ubuntu, putty, cortex-m

i connected a arm cortex-m3 kit to computer to send data serially
if i use putty on windows ,it works perfectly for same data ,but when i use putty on ubuntu it shows strange characters,
i researched on it they say run command ->locale

> my output ------->

```
LANG=en_IN
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
LC_CTYPE="en_IN"
LC_NUMERIC="en_IN"
LC_TIME="en_IN"
LC_COLLATE="en_IN"
LC_MONETARY="en_IN"
LC_MESSAGES="en_IN"
LC_PAPER="en_IN"
LC_NAME="en_IN"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IN"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IN"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IN"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IN"
LC_ALL=
```

whereas on internet everybodies output is like en_IN.UTF8 is this the reason ,how to change from en_IN to en_IN.UTF8 ,i have en_IN.UTF8 in my ubuntu cause it shows when i run command locale -a.

or is there any other reason ,i also have put translation->language in putty as UTF8(as per given on internet) still not working.

I have also tried on other computers and also tried minicom and picocom , i also made sure that settings of putty in windows and ubuntu are same, but results are same ,strange characters .how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Are you using the same baudrate that the kit uses?

Comment: yes the same baud rate , and its working fine in windows but not in ubuntu linux